# How to measure performance testing for Chat bots using jmeter or any tool?

Tags: jmeter, chatbot

I am setting up a performance testing using Jmeter for Chat bot application, How to start with it?

I have tried with JMeter WebSocket Samplers by Peter Doornbosch but not succeeded

Comment: How your chat bot works? is it using API requests you can check?

Comment: Chatbot will connect to websocket through websocket URL and Websocket will call API? Socket URL is https://test-dev-socket.testenv.co/socket.io

Answer (score 0):

To start, you need to find out how the chat client communicates with the server, i.e. what websocket messages it is sending to the server. To find out, ask the developers of the chat bot, or use a tool like WireShark to capture the communication and analyse it. Once you know which messages are exchanged, you can start setting up a test plan that simulates the client.

Answer (score 0):

For doing perf testing with jmeter I am using this plugin :-
https://github.com/damadei/BotServiceStressToolkit/blob/master/docs/creating.md

This will provide you with the correct options to perform chatbot testing .